# Are there any api to get categories of keywords?

Tags: web-services

Are there any api to get the categories of a keywords? 
Example, input "golf", return "sport", input "iPhone", return "consumer electronics"?

can google AdWords API do this?

Answer (score 0):

Wordnet http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet is the leading Open tool for the meanings and categorizations of English words. Here's an example:

```
 dog, domestic dog, Canis familiaris
    => canine, canid
       => carnivore
         => placental, placental mammal, eutherian, eutherian mammal
           => mammal
             => vertebrate, craniate
               => chordate
                 => animal, animate being, beast, brute, creature, fauna
                   => ...
```

So this will indicate that a dog is an animal

There are many interfaces, both Web services and APIs, see:
http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for "Semantics API". Or have a look at the downloadable Wikipedia dataset which contains popular terms like iPhone or celebrities (unlike a dictionary).